# ng-class with Evaluated Expression not working with class name passed as variable

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

This is my html

```
    <div ng-class="getClasses()"> </div>
```

The getClasses() method enter code here defined in controller as

```
    $scope.getClasses = function () {

   //another function call to get class name

   //To make short what ever the function returns it stores to variable 
     className i.e. 

    var className = 'proSpacerOne';

   //Similarly let

    var alternateClass = 'proSpacerOneA';


    return { className: false, alternateClass: true};
}
```

Here as my expectation 'proSpacerOneA' class should be applied to the 
But its applying class with name 'alternateClass'.

However if return the hard coded class name its working fine.

```
  return { 'proSpacerOne': false, 'proSpacerOneA': true};
```

What's wrong if I pass class name as variable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use bracket notation:

```
var className = 'proSpacerOne';
var alternateClass = 'proSpacerOneA';
var obj = {}
obj[className] = false;
obj[alternateClass] = true;

return obj;
```

Or ES6 object initializer (http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-initializer):

```
return { [className] : false, [alternateClass] : true }
```

Answer (score 0):

To use a variable as an object key, you have to use the`[]` synthax.

Change:

```
return { className: false, alternateClass: true};
```

To

```
var returnObj = {};
returnObj[className] = false;
returnObj[alternateClass] = true;
return returnObj;
```

Answer (score 0):

when angular trying to render

```
  ng-class="getClasses()"
```

expression,
 its fill class atribbute with retured object keys if value is not hoist false.

So if you return

```
{ className: false, alternateClass: true};
```

from your function angular will render class
 html tag like this

```
class="alternateClass"
```

you should use a different logic to pass class names to ng-class expression.
A valueable tutorail attached [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-many-ways-to-use-ngclass)